# serialize function is not working in php

Tags: php

Hi i get the value from post i used serialize function its showing wrong value. Its just displaying N.. pls help me

Php Code

```
$item_select_alpha = $_POST['item_select_alpha'];
for ($alpha = 1; $alpha <= count($item_select_alpha); $alpha++) {
    $serialise = serialize(array($item_select_alpha[$alpha]));
}
$item_quanity = $_POST['item_quanity'];
for ($qty = 1; $qty <= sizeof($item_quanity); $qty++) {
    $item_quan = serialize($item_quanity[$qty]);
}
print_r($item_quan);
exit;
```

HTML Code

```
<select class="item_select_alpha" name="item_select_alpha[]">
    <option value="">select the Alphabetic</option>
    {foreach $size_alpha as $sa}
    <option value="{$sa['size_id']}">{$sa['size_name']}</option>
    {/foreach}
</select>

<input type="text" class="item_quanity" name="item_quanity[]" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Are you sure that $_POST['item_quantity'] and $_POST['item_select_alpha'] are set ? Try to use isset() function when accessing post values, and try (for debugging purposes) to var_dump() $item_quantity and $item_select_alpha variables to see if everything is fine there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not add items to an array, but only changes the variable so it contains the last element. Try this:

```
    $serialise[] = serialize(array($item_select_alpha[$alpha]));

    $item_quan[] = serialize($item_quanity[$qty]);
```

Answer (score 0):

your variables in for loops will contains just the last element, you update their value at each iteration. $item_quan defined in the second loop won't be "printable" out of the loop...